# Printing on multiple lines instead of on a single line

Tags: tcl

I am trying to make multiple directories and also trying to search  and list all files found in a specific path.

```
proc filesearch {indir1 indir2 indir3 indir4 indir5} {
    set infile1 [glob -nocomplain -type f $indir1$indir2/*txt*]
    puts $infile1
}
```

When I puts `$infile1`, it puts all the file found into 1 long single line (as below). How can I split each file up into single line (put in `$infile1`).

The above `puts $infile1`, puts all into single line

```
a/b/c/d/a.txt a/b/c/d/b.xt a/b/c/d/c.txt a/b/c/d/d.txt
```

How do I puts out every file found into multiple lines?

```
a/b/c/d/a.txt
a/b/c/d/b.txt
a/b/c/d/c.txt
a/b/c/d/d.txt
```

Print all files found into individual line. Current output I see, list all the files in a single line separated with a space.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to loop through the list.

```
foreach elem $infile1 {
    puts $elem
}
```

**Reference :**  [foreach](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Just join the list of files using newline as a separator:

```
puts [join $infile1 \n]
```

Comment: If there are filenames with spaces, this won't work as well.   But a good solution if there are no spaces.

Comment: @BradLanam It works properly with file names with spaces.